# Help to compile tikz circuits library example

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

Very elementary question.  I am studying Tikz manual for drawing circuits.  Please guide me to compile the example given in page no. 547. Sec47.1.1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,positioning,shapes,fit}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,x=3cm,y=2cm,semithick,
every info/.style={font=\footnotesize},
small circuit symbols,
set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic,
set diode graphic=var diode IEC graphic,
set make contact graphic= var make contact IEC graphic]
% Let us start with some contacts:
\foreach \contact/\y in {1/1,2/2,3/3.5,4/4.5,5/5.5}
{
\node [contact] (left contact \contact) at (0,\y) {};
\node [contact] (right contact \contact) at (1,\y) {};
}
\draw (right contact 1) -- (right contact 2) -- (right contact 3)
-- (right contact 4) -- (right contact 5);
\draw (left contact 1) to [diode] ++(down:1)
to [voltage source={near start,
direction info={volt=3}},
resistor={near end,ohm=3}] ++(right:1)
to (right contact 1);
\draw (left contact 1) to [resistor={ohm=4}] (right contact 1);
\draw (left contact 1) to [resistor={ohm=3}] (left contact 2);
\draw (left contact 2) to [voltage source={near start,
direction info={<-,volt=8}},
resistor={ohm=2,near end}] (right contact 2);
\draw (left contact 2) to [resistor={near start,ohm=1},
make contact={near end,info’={[red]$S_1$}}]
(left contact 3);
\draw (left contact 3) to [current direction’={near start,info=$\iota$},
resistor={near end,info={$R=4\Omega$}}]
(right contact 3);
\draw (left contact 4) to [voltage source={near start,
direction info={<-,volt=8}},
resistor={ohm=2,near end}] (right contact 4);
\draw (left contact 3) to [resistor={ohm=1}] (left contact 4);
\draw (left contact 4) to [resistor={ohm=3}] (left contact 5);
\draw (left contact 5) to [resistor={ohm=4}] (right contact 5);
\draw (left contact 5) to [diode] ++(up:1)
to [voltage source={near start,
direction info={volt=3}},
resistor={near end,ohm=3}] ++(right:1)
to (right contact 5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have cut'n'pasted the code directly from the TikZ manual. The problem is that this way you don't get a reliable copy. In your case, two apostrophes are copied incorrectly.

Replace

```
make contact={near end,info’={[red]$S_1$}}]
```

by

```
make contact={near end,info'={[red]$S_1$}}]
```

and

```
\draw (left contact 3) to [current direction’={near start,info=$\iota$},
```

by

```
\draw (left contact 3) to [current direction'={near start,info=$\iota$},
```

Note the different single quotes (hardly visible, but different characters).